# Extracting 2 digits numbers from string

Tags: python, string, list, loops, slice

I have a file which contains string, from every string I need to append to my list every 2 digit number. Here's the file content:
https://pastebin.com/N6gHRaVA

I need to iterate every string and check if string on index[i] and on index[i+1] is digit, if yes, append those digits to list and slice the string from those 2 digits number,

for example the string:

string = '7469NMPLWX8384RXXOORHKLYBTVVXKKSRWEITLOCWNHNOAQIXO'
should work in this way:

1. Okay I have found digit 74, add 74 to my list and slice the string from 74 to the end
2. My string is now 69NMPLWX8384RXXOORHKLYBTVVXKKSRWEITLOCWNHNOAQIXO, I have found digit 69,add 69 to list and slice the string until I will find new 2-number digit.
   The problem is I always have error:

```
        if string[i].isdigit() and string[i+1].isdigit():
                               ~~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: string index out of range
```

```
f = open("file.txt")
read = f.read().split()
f.close()
for string in read:
    l = list()
    i = 0
    print(string)
    while i<len(string):
        if string[i].isdigit() and string[i+1].isdigit():
            l.append(string[i] + string[i+1])
            string = string[i+2:]
            i = 0
        else:
            i+=1
```

My program stops at string in line 31, which is the string:
'REDOHGMDPOXKFMHUDDOMLDYFAFYDLMODDUHMFKXOPDMGHODER5'

I have no idea how to do this slice iteration, and please, don't use regex.

Comment: why don't you want to use regex ?

Comment: It's exercise in which I can't use external libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **recursion**.
Here is what it would look like to deal with **one** of the strings.

**Part of the code**:

```py
my_string = '7469NMPLWX8384RXXOORHKLYBTVVXKKSRWEITLOCWNHNOAQIXO'
result_list = []

def read_string(s):
    result = ""
    for i,j in enumerate(s):
        if i>0 and s[i-1].isdigit() and s[i].isdigit():
            result = s[i-1] + s[i]
            result_list.append(result)
            read_string(s[i+1:])
            break;
            
    return (result_list)        
     
# Call the read_string function
x = read_string(my_string) 
print(x)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['74', '69', '83', '84']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going off the end of the string... Change:

```
 while i<len(string):
```

to:

```
 while i<len(string)-1:
```

And you should be fine.

If you were just looking at one character at a time, you could use your original `while`. The trick here is that you're always looking at a char and also "one ahead" of the char. So you have to shorten your check by one iteration to prevent going past the last char to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition i len(string). If string is not empty, this equals a positive intiger, which is evaluated as True. Hence, you created an endless loop, that meets it's end, when i gets greater then string length. Try this:

`while  i < len(string) -1:`

EDITED:
Apparently, i didn't notice which string gave you the error. As you check for i+1th element of string, when we star checking the last character, reaching for the next one gives an obvious error. So, there should be -1 in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are not stopping at the correct spot. You can just change your while loop to loop to

```py
while I < len(string) - 1:
```

If I may suggest a slightly cleaner approach, see below.

```py
f = open("file.txt")
read = f.read().split()
f.close()
for string in read:
    l = list()
    i = 0
    print(string)
    while i < len(string) - 1:
        numCheck = i + 1 # You call it more than once. Set to var
        ltr = string[i] + string[numCheck] # no need to call this multiple times, just set to a var
        if ltr.isdigit():
            l.append(ltr)
            string = string[numCheck:]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
        
print(l)
```

I changed your while loop to above and then put the calls you make more than once into a variable. Also since your list is initialized within the for loop you only keep the number from your last string if you want a list with all the numbers, simply move it out. Like so,

```py
f = open("file.txt")
read = f.read().split()
f.close()
l = list()
for string in read:
    i = 0
    print(string)
    while i < len(string) - 1:
        numCheck = i + 1 # You call it more than once. Set to var
        ltr = string[i] + string[numCheck] # no need to call this multiple times, just set to a var
        if ltr.isdigit():
            l.append(ltr)
            string = string[numCheck:]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
        
print(l)
```